# How to upload photo to page with Graph Api v2.2

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to create several apps before, but now with the v4 I can't make a simple photo upload to work :( I tried with the 'url' and with the 'source' parameter as well, but nothing works. I want to upload a photo to my own Facebook Page with some caption. I got the access token, the Access Token Debugger says, that it never expires and it has public_profile, read_stream, read_insights, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_photos permissions.

This my code right now:

```
$accessToken = "MY-ACCESS-TOKEN";

$session = new FacebookSession($accessToken);

$myfile = "file.png"; //created and saved via PHP GD functions

    if ( isset( $session ) ) {

        try {

            $message = "This is my message";

            $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session,
            'POST',
            '/'.$pageid.'/photos',
            array (
                'source'        => realpath("/path/to/" . $myfile),
                'message'       => $message,
                )
            );
        } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
            echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
            echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
            echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        /* handle the result */
    } else {
        // show login url
        echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
    }
```

Right now I get this error:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#324) Requires upload file' in /data/domains/
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: replace this line: `'source'        => realpath("/path/to/" . $myfile),`  with  `'source'        => '@' . realpath("/path/to/" . $myfile),`